# How to use react-hook-form inside Ionic Modal?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, react-hook-form

I'm trying to use `react-hook-form` with my Ionic React application. I'm using this simple form:

```
const Form: React.FC<{ color: string }> = ({ color }) => {
  const { handleSubmit, register } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    console.log(`%c${JSON.stringify(data)}`, `color: ${color}`);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input ref={register} name="name" type="text" />
      <input ref={register} name="surname" type="text" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

This component is working great, but when I'm trying to use it inside of a `IonModal`component, the `onSubmit` handler is not showing anything.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <IonApp>
      <Form color="green" />
      <IonModal
        isOpen={showModal}
        onDidDismiss={() => setShowModal(false)}
        children={<Form color="red" />}
      />
      <IonButton onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>Open Modal</IonButton>
    </IonApp>
  );
};
```

If I submit the first `Form`, the data is correctly printed in the console, but not if I submit the second one inside the `IonModal` component.
[Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/ionic-modal-form-bug-9y9r7) an example that shows this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see working example here...

https://codesandbox.io/s/ionic-modal-form-bug-48weq

I was able to get it working with the [Controller](https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller) from react-hook-form

```js
        <IonItem>
          <Controller
            as={<IonInput />}
            name="name"
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: true }}
            onChangeName="onIonChange"
            onChange={([selected]: any) => {
              return selected.detail.value;
            }}
          />
        </IonItem>
```

full blog post here [Using React Hook Form with Ionic React Components](https://dev.to/aaronksaunders/using-react-hook-form-with-ionic-react-components-2aab)

Comment: This will not work when using react-hook-form starting v6.0+ works with version 5.7.2 or below

Comment: see updated example - https://dev.to/ionic/using-react-hook-form-with-ionic-react-components-update-1463

Comment: Thanks for the quick post.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled up with some similar situation here, i solved it by rendering the `IonInput` with `onIonChange` calling to `onChange` with the value we need to:

```
<Controller
                    render={({ onChange, value }) => (
                      <IonInput
                        value={value}
                        type="tel"
                        placeholder="AA"
                        onIonChange={(e: CustomEvent<InputChangeEventDetail>) =>
                          onChange(
                            String(e.detail.value!).length < 2
                              ? `0${e.detail.value!}`
                              : e.detail.value!
                          )
                        }
                      />
                    )}
                    rules={{
                      required: true,
                    }}
                    name="expiryMonth"
                    control={control}
                  />
```

Instead of changing the value in the `Controller` component, we get the changing value and we process it inside of the `onIonChange` function, and the resulting value is passed to the `Controller`component's change method.